# Change the color of titles to include whole word in Awesome CV

Tags: awesome-cv

I am currently using [Awesome CV template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) on overleaf for my cover letter, and one thing that I noticed is that the first three letters of the sections are highlighted in color. On the resume, this looks cool because it is consistent throughout. However, I find it a little odd looking that both 'Why' are one word fully colored and 'About' is only three letters highlighted but it isn't the whole word.

Is there any way to change the coloring of the headers so that 'About' in the section heading is fully colored?

Here is a screenshot from the template to be clearer:
[image: Template]

Instead of just 'Abo' colored in red, I would like 'About' colored in red.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not sure where to do this in the code.

Comment: I had the same problem, the answer posted here doesn't really address the problem. I found a way to make it work, explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563898/changing-awesomecv-section-highlighting-to-highlight-whole-first-word). Posting as an answer to this question for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 9):

`awesomecv.cls` defines the `\@sectioncolor` such that it would only apply the colouring to the first three tokens:

```
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{{\color{awesome}#1#2#3}}{#1#2#3}%
}
```

So for the entire heading to be coloured (and assuming you *always* want it to be coloured so we can ignore the boolean for now), you can add these lines  before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@sectioncolor{\color{awesome}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

To color the entire word "About" in Awesome CV rather than just the first three letters I used this in `coverletter.tex`:

```
\lettersection{Abo{\color{awesome}ut} Me}
```

I added the following above `\begin{document}` as well:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gold(metallic)}{HTML}{D4AF37}

\colorlet{awesome}{gold(metallic)}
```